# WCF Application Design

Tags: wcf, oracle, ibm-mq

I am starting the development of a simple WCF application that queries data from an Oracle 11g DB table and enqueues a message into Websphere MQ 5.3. I am not sure of the best way to design this application.

Should I use an Oracle trigger to notify WCF when a change is made to the table or should I use WCF to continually poll the DB table for changes?

Also, how can get I WCF to communicate with Websphere MQ 5.3? I've researched enough to see that the newer version of Websphere MQ 7.1 comes with a custom channel for WCF but I don't know how to get WCF to work with 5.3.

I've been told that we don't use Microsoft Biztalk or Oracle Database Change Notification(ODBN).
Should I recommend to my supervisor that we upgrade Websphere MQ to 7.1 and also use Biztalk or ODBN?

I am new to using WCF, Oracle, and Websphere MQ and am unsure which direction to take.
Any links or resources to help me figure this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MQ 5.3 is out of support. So it is not recommended to use an out of support product. As you found WCF support is not available in MQ v5.3. WCF support is available from MQ v7.0.1. So you have to upgrade to at least MQ v7.0.1.

MQ WCF provides a custom channel using which web services can be hosted on MQ and clients can call those web services using the custom channel.

If your intention is to use MQ WCF for just putting messages into a queue and not develop any web service, then it would be better to look at either MQ .NET classes or XMS .NET classes. MQ .NET classes provide OO API for messaging with MQ queue/topic whereas XMS .NET provides a JMS like API.

My 2 cents on other part: It is better to receive notifications from Oracle DB when a change happens than polling. There could be way in Oracle where you could register a callback or listener that gets called when change occurs to a table.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Shashi. I spoke with my supervisor yesterday and we will be upgrading to MQ 7.0.1.